# Liquibase: How to change default postgresql schema

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, liquibase

By default liquibase create all objects on the public schema. However I created another schema and I want liquibase to use it.

I changed database URL by appending searchpath=mySchema

```
jdbc:postgresql://${host}:${db.port}/${db.name}?searchpath=mySchema
```

I also tried appending it with currentSchema=mySchema

```
jdbc:postgresql://${dbhost}:${db.port}/${db.name}?currentSchema=mySchema
```

but it both ways liquibase is still pointing into public schema.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change PG user account so that the right default schema is set at database connection time with something like:

```
alter role r in database b set search_path='s';
```

Comment: After I executed it, I'm facing new error: Unable to update database. liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
  Position: 14 [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE databasechangeloglock.....

Comment: Did you give privileges to user account to use the schema with: "grant all on schema s to r;"  ?

Comment: It worked fine but still facing an issue! Once I change the search_path within the connection string to another schema, liquibase is able to create all objects on the new selected schema, but anywhere I'm querying the tables of the selected schema it says relation does not exist, Although it's exists. it seems that it's creating tables on the selected schema, but still relating to them using original schema! (I think a part of the issue is that databasechangelog table created on the first schema only, and second schema still using it)!

Comment: When accessing the new tables in the new schema you need to give schema name like "s.t" (for table t in schema s) or to add schema "s" to search_path setting.

Comment: I don't want to give schema name, I want to simply include schema name in my connection string and it should take care of it: jdbc:postgresql://${host}:${db.port}/${db.name}?searchpath=mySchema... but it's always pointing to the schema that I set on postgres directly, and not affected by the search path which is included on the connection string

Answer (score 3):

You have to instruct Liquibase to create its meta tables `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOCK` in your schema as well. Just put the following line into your Liquibase properties file:

```
liquibaseSchemaName=mySchema
```

See also https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the default schema, that helped me to generate the first changeset. Set this property in the liquibase.yaml file:

```
defaultSchemaName: clm_dev
```